# TSQL - Empty rows returned in a cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, cursor, no-data

apologies as this may be a very dumb question -- I am working with a cursor it joins a temporary table of about 697K rows and a function that returns 78K rows. *(this i should add is an improvement it used to be worse)*. The cursor goes through and matches on two values in both 'tables' and updates a third. This takes 6 or so hours. Which is absurd. We are trying to come up with ways to  make this more efficient.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. But my inquiry is this --

[image]

It seems to  be returning data that looks as follows (in a lot of cases empty information). Can I restrict the code to say where ... data isn't null ... but its not that its coming back Null its empty/nonexistent rows. I am thinking if there is a way to exclude rows like that we may limit our data pool. But I don't entirely know what this means.

```
declare @season int = 21

DECLARE @match varchar(55)
declare @perf_no int
declare @order_dt datetime

DECLARE   @price CURSOR
SET       @price = CURSOR FOR
SELECT    distinct match_criteria, perf_no, order_dt
FROM      #prices
OPEN      @price
FETCH NEXT
FROM      @price INTO @match, @perf_no, @order_dt
WHILE     @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

select  @match, @perf_no, @order_dt, x.price as 'amount'
from    #prices p
join    dbo.[LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal] (@season, @order_dt) x on p.perf_price_type = x.perf_price_type and p.zone_no = x.zone_no
where   match_criteria = @match and perf_no = @perf_no

FETCH NEXT
FROM @price INTO @match, @perf_no, @order_dt
END
CLOSE @price
DEALLOCATE @price
```

Here is  sample of what #prices and # our function returns.

## prices

```
pkg_no  perf_no zone_no price_type  order_dt                    price   perf_price_type match_criteria
12      144     2707    1073        2018-09-03  00:00:00.000    NULL    115769          O5716788P1517Z2707
12      123     2707    1073        2018-09-03  00:00:00.000    NULL    115840          O5716788P1517Z2707
12      887     2707    1073        2018-09-03  00:00:00.000    NULL    115521          O5716788P1517Z2707
```

Function:

```
perf_price_type zone_no price   min_price   enabled editable_ind
115521          2678    12.00   12.00       Y       N
115521          2679    61.00   61.00       Y       N
115521          2680    41.00   41.00       Y       N
```

What the cursor does is update the price in the #prices table based on that of the function. (we used the cursor to only limit it to certain performance/limited criteria). But i'm open to suggestions. and advice as to how to improve this.

Comment: First question to ask yourself do you need a cursor?  If not dont use it.  There are few times you actually need to use a cursor.  Second, most likely you can not have blank rows, but without seeing your code we cant help

Comment: @Brad, I would love to get away from the cursor, but I think in this case we may  need it. I'll update the above ticket with the code (or as much of it as I can)

Comment: @Cato its a system Function, I will double check I (honestly don't think its indexed at all) -- I just attempted to add one and got this message: Index cannot be created on object 'LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal' because the object is not a user table or view.

Comment: Not sure what the LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal does but looks like you could possibly replace the variables with columns from the #prices table?  And just do it in a single query??  Also if your getting blank rows, check how your #prices table is being populated

Comment: To identify what causes empty rows you have to identify specific data which results in empty rows. Unless you provide a minimal repro no advice is possible. "Such is your data... or code" - that's it.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I attached a data set of each piece and the cursor that displays it. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the empty data.  Is there another piece of info I can help provide to help sort this issue.

Comment: @Brad the LFT_GET_PRICES_seasonal pulls data together gets an identifyer (perf_price_type) for each zone and the price information you see. It is normalized to pull that way, our cursor goes through finds each match.

Comment: Ok, it still seems like you could do it on a straight join, or recreate parts of what that does with joins and avoide the cursor all together.  But for blank rows, I would confirm what is in the #prices table?  Is there blank/bad data in there?  Maybe data in #prices is not returning anything from your LFT_GET_PRICES_seasonal (which seems to be the case)  or there is missing/blank data for some of the columns in #prices resulting in blank rows from LFT_GET_PRICES_seasonal

Comment: @Brad I'll review the prices for bad data. But the update script requires two parameters to be passed to the function (they come from the #prices table). update `#prices
set  price = x.price
from #prices p
join dbo.[LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal] (@season, p.order_dt) x on p.perf_price_type = x.perf_price_type and p.zone_no = x.zone_no` The issue is that an error is generated `The multi-part identifier "p.order_dt" could not be bound.` Because I'd normally get order_dt in the cursor

Comment: @YelizavetaYR `and p.zone_no = x.zone_no` this join condition is not met for given sample data.

Comment: @IvanStarostin what do you mean -- this condition is not met for given sample of data. If its not met, then shouldn't the row not come back at all

Comment: Oh, so this is okay that particular `select`s result in nothing, you just don't want to **see** those empty resultsets, right?

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes, I'm hoping to exclude it in an effort to streamline the code.

Comment: "What the cursor does is update the price in the #prices table based on that of the function" Then you didn't post the correct code. The code you posted does not include an update statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, i changed my cursor to do a select for testing mostly, but yes you are correct in your statement about the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you want to update the #price table with the results from the table valued function.
You can do that by using `cross apply` instead of a cursor.
Since you didn't post proper sample data I have no way of testing my answer, but if it does what you need it should be doing that lightning-fast compared to a cursor.

```
DECLARE @season int = 21

UPDAET p
SET price = x.Price
FROM #Prices p
CROSS APPLY  
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.LFT_GET_PRICES_Seasonal(@season, order_dt) udf
    WHERE udf.perf_price_type = p.perf_price_type 
    AND udf.zone_no = p.zone_no
) x
```

SQL works best with a set based approach and not a procedural approach, which is why you want to avoid loops and cursors whenever possible and only use them as a last resort.

Comment: I love avoiding cursors and loops, and the data i wasn't able to provide much data as its tricky to share. but let me test this. thank you.

Comment: just to clarify, the order_dt comes from prices in the cross apply yes? as a parameter. If so this is very cool, i have to learn more about this.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Unfortunately [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply) on `apply` is not very detailed, but it's always a good start...

Comment: It looks like it worked, we got the whole process down from over 6 hours to about 30+ seconds. Thank you. I'm reviewing outputs to make sure logic is correct but it looks good so far.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Well, I'd say that's a pretty good improvement... Glad to help :-)